# adb find phone partitions

Tags: android, shell, adb

I need the command to find the partition of all Android devices.

For example, on some Samsung phones, you can use the following command to list the device partitions:

```sh
adb shell
ls -al /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name
```

It turns out that on all Android devices, finding the partition's address is in `/dev/block/platform/xxxx/by-name`.

How to find the `xxxx` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toybox find`:

```
toybox find /dev/block/platform -type d -name by-name
```

Toybox is included with Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and all later Android versions.

Comment: @jared_Rummler thanks its work with android 6.0 and later ok , How can we find Android below 6.0?

Comment: You can try `ls -R /dev/block/platform | grep by-name`

Comment: Your job is great 
It works for all versions of Android

Answer (score 0):

Usually

```
getprop ro.boot.bootdevice
```

Comment: actually this is the answer for the question `How to find the xxxx folder?` To get partitions list just use `ls -al /dev/block/platform/"ro.boot.device"/by-name`